# Can you set keyboard shortcuts to use more than 1 key

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

In windows 7 you can set Keyboard Shortcuts to file/folder shortcuts, the shortcuts are always Ctrl + Alt + [YOU KEY]

what i want to know is can you create these shortcuts with more than 1 key so instead of Ctrl + Alt + K you have Ctrl + Alt + K + A + M

i ask this because i have a keyboard and mouse which i can program some of the buttons and am thinking of creating shortcut combinations for some shortcuts so that they are more unique and less likely to be used in a program (eg. the shortcut to Kamidori Alchemy Miester could be set to Ctrl + Alt + E + U + K + A + M + D + O + R + I which could never be in a program cause it's more than 10 keys)

Comment: Take a look at http://www.bayden.com/slickrun/ and see if that might give you something close enough to what you want. I believe you don't need the keys to be pressed all at once, entering something should be fine. You are aware that you can most likely hit the windows key and enter "kamidori" to find and run the program from your start menu, right? That already is in fact shorter than what you have in mind ;-)

Comment: @TheUser1024 entering "kamidori" after pressing the Windows Key doesn't work cause the .exe file is age.exe (not sure if it was Eushully or the translation patch) and the folder is in Japanese (changing it would break translation patch installation), same with the ~ What a Beautiful ~ games

Comment: with 8 states of Ctrl+Shift+Alt plus letters/digits/symbols/function keys you already have hundreds of possible keys. Using more normal keys will make it harder and more confuse. That said, some programs do have the ability to have multikey shortcuts, like VS `Ctrl+K, C` (press the first one, release then press the next)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so because having a shortcut with more than one key is not very practical. The use of shortcuts are to shorten the time it takes to open a program. I now use linux so I don't really know but I  used to use windows. But have you tried?

Comment: yeh, using the example i used in the question, i put in E and the value of Shortcut becomes Ctrl + Alt + E but when i put in U it then changes to Ctrl + Alt + U, i was wondering if there was some other way that allows for longer than 1 key